# Nested Border Radius Problem

Tags: css

I have a `div` with `border-radius: 20px` applied to it. The first element inside of said `div` is an `h2` with a background color. The `div's` radius does not affect the `h2` at all so I end up with two pointed corners sticking out of my div. I tried applying a radius to the top right and top left corners of the `h2` but this left a tiny sliver of white between the `div's` corner and the `h2's` corner.

I tried decreasing the `h2` border radius but to completely remove the white it ends up bulging out from the `div` again....

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZJCS/)

My CSS is essentially:

```
#div {
border radius: 20px;
border: 2px solid #000;
}

#h2 {
margin-top: 0px;
border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: What browser is this in? In Safari 5.1 and Chrome 13.0.782.112, it looks correct to me. A box with white background, black curved border, red headline clipped inside the border.

Comment: I'm seeing it in Chrome 13.0.782.112 and FF 3.5.19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have some typo in your code
`border-radius` not `border radius`
Then, if you apply `border-radius` for all corners for an element that have an height less than `border-radius` itself then browser just apply the rounded corner on half of the height of the element. For example if you have a `div` that have `10ox` height and if you apply `5px` radius for every corner then browser just applies `5px` of your `10px` `border-radius` to each corner. It doesn't mean you got `5px` `border-radius` it means just 5 top pixels will affect.

In your sample the `div` doesn't have enough height to accept `20px` `border-radius`.
If you apply a `height` more that `40px` then you can have perfect `border-radius` effect.

Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L9Kq/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I'm not sure I understand what is wrong here. In the fiddle I posted the div has a height of 300px so it should be able to work with at 20px border-radius. Why doesn't that example work?

Comment: Let's say you have a div 40 by 40 pixels, then if you apply 20px border radius it would transfer to a circle. But if you apply more than 20px it doesn't matter how much, it would get just first 20px. look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L6snN/

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I'm still having trouble sorting this out though. Here is a fiddle with my exact CSS. What am I doing wrong here? I'm still seeing small slivers of white between the red h2 and the div border. http://jsfiddle.net/EZWqM/1/

Comment: It seems ok in my Chrome 14 on Mac!

Comment: Hm, yeah, it was just looking odd in Chrome on Windows. I fixed it by using overflow: hidden; for webkit browsers and decreasing the internal border radius for FF. Seemed to work just fine then. Thank you!